# Failed to evaluate SPeL expression in @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I Have a simple expression in @PreAuthorize annotation:

`@PreAuthorize("#userId == authentication.principal.id")`

But the response is:

> Failed to evaluate expression '#userId == authentication.principal.id'

Here is method signature:

`fun updateGeneralProfileInfo(@PathVariable userId: Long, authentication: Authentication)` (Kotlin)

In debug mode I saw that in runtime `authentication.principal` is UserPrincipal object and it contains the `id` field.

Btw expression `#userId == authentication.principal` works (of course it always return false, but at least not an exception)

Hep please!

Comment: As what stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize), you can directly use `principal` expression. Can you try to write your annotation as `@PreAuthorize("#userId == principal.id")`?

Comment: The same result

Comment: Could you share the code that how do your load the use detail, and set principal ?